# C++ How to store the nodes of an in order traversal into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, inorder

I have an in-order traversal function like such

```
void Inorder(node *root)
{
    node* array;
    array = new node[arraySize];


    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    Inorder(root->left); //visit left sub-tree
    

    std::cout << "Word: " << root->key << std::endl
              << "Occurance: " << root->count << std::endl; //print root key and its count

    Inorder(root->right); //visit right sub-tree
    
}
```

In order to sort it any further I need to store the node transversed in an array however im not sure i can accomplish this. Visually i want something like this

```
node array[0] = transversedNode;
```

Ive tried adding root to the array
Ive tried adding  Inorder(root->left) to the array when Inorder is of type node

But none of these accomplish what i need. Is it possible to store the nodes transversed into an array? Thankyou

Comment: you could use `std::vector` and push_back elements, like you would print them. You can pass this vector as a second argument by reference and pass is down the recursion.

Comment: You need to have single variable with array, or better vector, to put elements into. This can be accomplished in number of ways: put it as function argument, as class member if this is function in class, as static variable.

Comment: @Unlikus what would the vector type be?  as key is string and count is int

Comment: @DickChang The vector type should  be `std::vector<Node*>`.

Answer (score 0):

As others commented already, you can replace your array declaration with an `std::vector<Node*>` and return it:

```
void InorderRecursive(Node *root, std::vector<Node*>& nodes)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    InorderRecursive(root->left, nodes); //visit left sub-tree

    std::cout << "Word: " << root->key << std::endl
              << "Occurance: " << root->count << std::endl; //print root key and its count
    nodes.push_back(root);

    InorderRecursive(root->right, nodes); //visit right sub-tree
}

std::vector<Node*> Inorder(Node *root)
{
    std::vector<Node*> nodes;    
    InorderRecursive(root, nodes);
    return nodes;
}
```

I added an additional function `InorderRecursive` that calls itself and is called by `Inorder`. It has `std::vector<Node*>` reference as an additional parameter. The original vector is constructed in `Inorder` and passed. This way you have a single container, to avoid copying the whole thing.

Comment: You should do push_back(root) after traversing left subtree, not before, unless it will be preorder traverse.

Comment: Every call creates a new vector, which allocates from the heap for the push_back, and when it returns, is copied into the current vector.  It would be _much_ more efficient to pass the same vector through to the recursive calls, and they all add values directly it without all that copying and allocating.  That just leaves the initial call: write a 2nd, non-recursive function which does nothing but takes the root pointer, declares the vector and passes them into the recursive function, returning the vector. (If reducing allocation is important.)